# Undefined offset while randomising a variable?

Tags: php, random, error-handling

```
$units = array(
    "R" =>"Kid Pan", "PO Krillen", "Android #16", "Android #19",
    'SR'=>'Vegeta', 'Piccolo', 'Botamo', 'SSJ2GokuGT', 'CaptainGinyu',
    'SSR'=>'TEQPerfectCell', 'STRGogeta', 'PHYKidBuu', 'STRBroly',
);
    echo $units[rand(0, count($units) - 1)] . "\n";
```

This code works fine, but sometimes there are errors, some with differnet numbers?
For example; **"NOTICE Undefined offset: 10 on line number 8"** and **NOTICE Undefined offset: 12 on line number 8**

By the way, I'm testing this code with *http://phptester.net/*

(I'm a noob - sorry :/)

Comment: I don't mind the more downvotes coming but is there a way for it to randomise using a button?

Comment: issue in   rand(0, count($units) - 1..it some time returm more then your array index value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use  `array_rand`

```
echo $units[ array_rand($units)] . "\n";
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Comment: thank you! do you know if i can randomise using a button instead of refreshing?

Comment: The button is invoked client side while your function work server  side .. so just a suggestion you should code a function invoked  by ajax on click button and manage the values  return using the success function for ajax .. but as in previous comment . you should post a new properly described  question

Answer (score 0):

You can not echo an array.
You have use print_r() to see values of an array

```
print_r( $units[ array_rand($units) ] ) . "\n";
```